# How to combine 2 2D lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I am pretty new to python, and I have a little problem.

I need to combine two 2D lists like this:

```
list1= [[some,1],[thing,5]]
list2= [[some,1],[other,1],[thing,5]]
```

result should be like this:

```
result= [[some,2],[other,1],[thing,10]]
```

Comment: Does order matter? If so, what should the order be?

Comment: No, order is not important, I just need to add new thing and sum same thing

Comment: Do you have to use lists? Seems like you're using them as [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: You should use a `collections.Counter`.

Comment: It should be lists, unfortunately :/

Comment: Seriously 3 upvotes to a question that is missing any effort what so ever?

Comment: This question **lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem** because the problem is that the poster didn't attempt anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> list1 = [['some',1],['thing',5]]
>>> list2= [['some',1],['other',1],['thing',5]]
>>>
>>> [[k,v] for k,v in (Counter(dict(list1)) + Counter(dict(list2))).items()]
[['thing', 10], ['other', 1], ['some', 2]]
```

Or if a list of tuples is acceptable:

```
>>> (Counter(dict(list1)) + Counter(dict(list2))).items()
[('thing', 10), ('other', 1), ('some', 2)]
```

Using tuples seems to make more sense here.

You should consider if you actually need the final result to be a list. If order is not important (as you say it isn't), then the dictionary `Counter(dict(list1)) + Counter(dict(list2))` will probably suffice on its own.

```
>>> Counter(dict(list1)) + Counter(dict(list2))
Counter({'thing': 10, 'some': 2, 'other': 1})
```

Comment: Ty very much the 1st thing is exactly what I needed !

Comment: Can I use that collections.counter even for subtraction?

Comment: @user3648145 Yes, you can.