# How to subtract two 2D lists in python?

Tags: python, list

**I need to subract two 2D lists like this**:

```
list1= [['some',2],['other',1],['thing',5]]

list2= [['some',1],['thing',5]]
```

**result should be like this**:

```
result= [['some',1],['other',1],['thing',0]]
```

**or**

```
result= [['some',1],['other',1]]
```

It should be a list, not a dictionary; the order doesn't matter.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? show us some code to talk about

Comment: You can literally flip one operand in the [answer you got to your almost identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714227/how-to-combine-2-2d-lists-in-python) and get your answer.

Comment: 3 downvotes here, and 3 upvotes on their previous question. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
list1= [['some',2],['other',1],['thing',5]]

list2= [['some',1],['thing',5]]
c1 = Counter({item[0]: item[1] for item in list1})
c2 = Counter({item[0]: item[1] for item in list2})
result = [[key, value] for key, value in (c1-c2).items()]

result
[['other', 1], ['some', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it guys like this:

```
tmp=[[k,v] for k,v in (Counter(dict(list1)) - Counter(dict(list2))).items()]
```

Ty guys for answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d1, d2 = dict(list1), dict(list2)
>>> d = {key: d1[key] - d2.get(key, 0) for key in d1}
>>> d.items()
[('thing', 0), ('other', 1), ('some', 1)]
>>> map(list, d.items())
[['thing', 0], ['other', 1], ['some', 1]]
```

Comment: You should explain the code you posted.

Answer (score -2):

Code:

```
list1 = [['some',2], ['other',1], ['thing',5]]
list2 = [['some',1], ['thing',5]]

def list_substractor(l1, l2):
    d1 = dict(l1)
    d2 = dict(l2)

    for key, value in d1.items():
        if key in d2.keys():
            d1[key] = d1[key] - d2[key]

    for item in set( set(d2.keys()) - set(d1.keys())):
        d1[item] = -d2[item]

    return [[key, value] for key, value in d1.items()]

print list_substractor(list1, list2)
print list_substractor(list2, list1)
```

Output:

```
[['thing', 0], ['other', 1], ['some', 1]]
[['thing', 0], ['other', -1], ['some', -1]]
```

Comment: At least test the code once. Clearly visible Syntax errors.